# Is using webpack alongside wagtail for transpiling scss and es7+ script a good practice?

Tags: wagtail

I'm new to the django wagtail ecosystem and I was wondering what was the prefered way to add SCSS or ES7 javascript to my project.

For now what I plan to do is creating a webpack build pipeline that will output my transpilled files to the static folders.

Is this a good practice ?
Is there a better way to do this while keeping the hot-reloading feature?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have anything for JS, but for SASS I'm using django-libsass. Been working well so far. Here is a walkthrough for setting it up: [Link](https://vix.digital/insights/setting-foundation-sass-wagtail/)

Comment: thanks for the tip but I guess i'll stick with webpack for now since every transpilation I need is in the same pipeline with that tool

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed a common practice to have a webpack build pipeline to output transpilled files into the static folders.

It seems that is is possible to get hot-reloading with [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader/tree/master/examples/hot-reload) (see also this [usage example article](http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/)) or [django-webpacker](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/django-webpacker), although I haven't tried myself so I can't guarantee it.

As a side note, and *this is just my personal opinion*, it's not a bad practice but I wouldn't call it a good practice either, more the best-we've-got practice. Today, Django is very much in the same situation that Rails was before v5, trying to handle assets with its own pipeline which hasn't kept up with the recent JavaScript evolution. The packages linked above try to do something similar to Rails 5 but it still feels a bit awkward.